# Folder Doesn't create On SharePoint location

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm-2013

MS Dynamics CRM plugin called on Create of entity record. In plugin we used dws service, and the user has full control.

When the plugin triggers the response of `Dws.CreateFolder(...);` the result is `"<Result/>"`.
But actually folder doesn't create on Sharepoint location.
but sometimes folder is created.

Code:

```
_Dws = new Dws();
_Dws.Url = sharepointConfig.SiteUrl + "_vti_bin/DWS.asmx";
_Dws.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sharepointConfig.UserName, sharepointConfig.Password);
string returnDWS = _Dws.CreateFolder(destinationFolder);
pTraceService.Trace("DWS : " + returnDWS);
```

Also Create folder by using **webdav "MKCOL"** but also same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the code you are sharing is part of a Dynamics CRM plugin class. Variable `_Dws` seems to be a field of this class. Usage of fields in plugin classes is usually not thread-safe, because plugin class instances are shared by multiple threads.

Due to race conditions you may observe that the plugin is behaving inconsistently.

Remove all class level variables from your plugin and replace them by locally scoped variables. (Often a better choice is to move all business logic to separate classes.)